# Average of sum of column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 2 columns : dates (1st of the month) and values. Each date can appear an unknown number of time. I am trying to find a formula that would make a yearly average of the sum of the value for each month.

I can easily make several sumproducts to have the sum of values for each month and then average but I would prefer to limit the size of the formula.

Does anyone has an idea on how to do that, or if that's even possible?

Comment: You can use AVERAGEIF, but PivotTable is easier

Comment: As I said in an other comment, PivotTable will only let me Sum or Average while I need Sum the Average

Comment: sum of the year divided by 12, or you have missing months?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that dates are in `A` column and values in `B` column.

The easiest way would be:

1) In third column (`C`), store the integers indicating the month. You will get this result by simple `=MONTH()` Excel function, ex.: `=MONTH(A1)`, etc.

2) To get the average from particular month, say September (9th month), you need to enter the formula:

```
= SUMIF(C:C,"=9",B:B)/COUNTIF(C:C,"=9")
```

If you want the average for different month, you just change the `9` in `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a pivot table, then drag the date in row field and values in value field. Then change the field setting of the values to 'average'.

Comment: Sadly PivotTable will only let me Sum or Average, I really need to have a Sum for each month then Average each month for the year

Comment: Well do you want to aggregate the data (like the pivot does) or do you just want to add some formulars in your table?

Comment: I would want to aggregate the data, but the pivot don't do the calculations I need